# node-sass vulnerability issue in angular-8

Tags: angular, node-sass

I was facing node-sass vulnerability issue in my angular 6 app , so to remove it I upgraded my angular app to version 8 .

as the official documentation says we have now started using native javascript compiler instead of sass compilers

I don't see any node-sass version on my package.json or  package.lock.json file but there are still vulnerability because of node-sass.

can anyone tell the reason for it and a way to resolve it 
thanks !!

Comment: List all installed packages and see if any uses node-sass

Comment: I downgraded the angular to version 7 as there were some node version issues during jules build .

node-sass vulnerabilities present there and there are some packages which have dependency on node-sass .

have gone through a lot of github-threads but none of the solution worked for me